# Rails return hexadecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails, develop a project with scaffold and associations. The project enters regions and cities. When I add the regions all very well, but when I want to add a city that belongs to a region, the region shows me as hexadecimal.

I read, which was to add to_s, but where I add?

Sorry my english, im Chilean :D.

Nombre_ciudad   Region
   Arica        #Region:0x007f1b07f089e8    Show    Edit    Destroy

New Ciudad

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to_s` method goes in the model class, in this case `Region`.

```
class Region
    def to_s
        name
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand.

my model ciudad:

class Ciudad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
def to_s
 ???
end
end
My model Region

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
 def to_s
   region???
 end  
end
the _form:

<%= simple_form_for(@ciudad) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
   <%= f.input :nombre_ciudad %>
   <%= f.association :region %>
  </div>

<div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
The column name in DB is region_id

Sorry, im idiot!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what exaclty you're trying to do, but as associations go....

```
class Ciudad < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :region

 end
end
```

Ciudads can only belong to one region, while a region will have many ciudads...

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many: ciudads

 end  
end
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `to_s` but `.to_s` is a way of converting a variable to a string, ".to_string"

Hope this helps.